# How to take screenshot of Android(Emulator) using this library and where can i get the screenshots

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, screenshot

I had installed this library http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/.

I had started my Android emulator ,when i run the run.sh file it is saying "Service Started Sucessfully".

How Should i or where can i get the Screen shots of my emulator.I am using all latest versions.Thank You.

Comment: @Hitendra no i am directly running using adb from terminal..i want to take the screenshot of whatever activity is running on the phone.actually my project is ScreenCast

Comment: Hey Albert! Did you get the answer? If yes, then please guide.

Answer (score 4):

Open Eclipse > open DDMS View > Select your Emulator out of the list > press the little blinking Camera Icon near where you select your Emulator from the list

Hope you find it.

Comment: I want a code which will start a service which will send me Whatever is displayed on the emulator(phone) to pc in a frame buffer,actually my project is ScreenCast

Answer (score 0):

```
import pl.polidea.asl.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection; 
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.graphics.*;

public class ScreenshotDemo extends Activity {

/*
 * The ImageView used to display taken screenshots.
 */
private ImageView imgScreen;

private ServiceConnection aslServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        aslProvider = IScreenshotProvider.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};
private IScreenshotProvider aslProvider = null;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgScreen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgScreen);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTakeScreenshot); 
    btn.setOnClickListener(btnTakeScreenshot_onClick); 

    // connect to ASL service
    //Intent intent = new Intent(ScreenshotService.class.getName());
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, ScreenshotService.class);
    //intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
    bindService (intent, aslServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unbindService(aslServiceConn);
    super.onDestroy();
}


private View.OnClickListener btnTakeScreenshot_onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            if (aslProvider == null)
                Toast.makeText(ScreenshotDemo.this, R.string.n_a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if (!aslProvider.isAvailable())
                Toast.makeText(ScreenshotDemo.this, R.string.native_n_a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                String file = aslProvider.takeScreenshot();
                if (file == null)
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenshotDemo.this, R.string.screenshot_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenshotDemo.this, R.string.screenshot_ok, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
                    imgScreen.setImageBitmap(screen);

                }
            }
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // squelch
        }

    }
};
}
```

Comment: 1).Will this code send the screenshot buffer to the pc of Whatever is displayed on the screen                                         2).Where this code should be compiled and run ,should it be installed in the emulator...actually my project is ScreenCast

Answer (score 0):

DDMS has a feature to taking screenshots of views.

In Eclipse, open DDMS perspective and click on screen capture icon in Devices layout.

Comment: I want a code which will start a service which will send me Whatever is displayed on the emulator(phone) to pc in a frame buffer,actually my project is ScreenCast