# Capture scrollable content to Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to get a screenshot in a scrollable view (ViewPager), but I´m only getting a image from what is in the screen.

I have a Viewpager with two childrens

> android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
>
> NoSaveStateFrameLayout

I´m using this code to get the screenshot

```
private Bitmap screenShot(View view) {

    Bitmap capture = null;
    
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    capture = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    
    return capture;
}
```

I need to capture the hole content, the scrollable content that is not in screen yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can create bitmap of any view by following method

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

simply use above with your parent view and create bitmap of entire activity

Comment: I have tried this before and I´m getting the same problem.

Comment: Don't forget about android texture size limit. It shouldn'be be larger than 2048*2048. This could be a problem for newest devices.

Comment: split your UI in multiple view and capture in parts

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to fix that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650049/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-layout-in-android)

You have to get the child height in Scrollable View.