# How to Scale, Move & Zoom In, Zoom Out Textview?

Tags: android, scale, textview, translate

I want to Scale, Move & Zoom IN, Zoom Out Textview in My project.
Is there any library for do this task?

Refere App TextGram i want to make same as like this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=codeadore.textgram

All done like clipart, stickers etc i faced issue only in Text drawaing like this.

Comment: you want to move the textview as in drag and drop it?

Comment: I want to move Textview also scale, rotate on touch like imageview>
refere this link for ImageView MultiTouch
http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

Comment: Can be done, if its is having a static value then you can take it's screenshot and then convert that bitmap to an image and then use this method you just showed.

Comment: Thanks Tushar but i don't want this with bitmap because i also perform autowrap text on zoom.
Refere App TextGram i want to make same as like this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=codeadore.textgram

Comment: Textgram  is using bitmap itself.

Comment: No i don't think so that they use bitmap for textview because it is not wrap text in bitmap i think.have u any solution same as like textgram.If u have plz provide me.

Comment: I just saw that application, it is bitmap. trust me on this. Take [screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10651384/3531756) of the textview and then use [this](http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/) method on it.

Comment: @Tushar. Okay you say that they use bitmap then how wrap text of bitmap when zoom in & i think when user zoom it every time not possible to create new bitmap it takes load.

Answer (score 1):

`View Animation` is what you need. For example, make `myanim.xml` inside `res/anim` folder with this content:

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.4"
           android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

and in your `Activity` class:

```
TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim);
mText.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

Read more [here in Android Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) or [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html).

Comment: Thanks @Kasra but i want to perform this on Finger touch.

Comment: Like drag and drop you mean?

Comment: Ya drag, scale like Imageview

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try below code custom view with having facility to add zoomview 

    package <your package>;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

/**
 * Zooming view.
 */
public class ZoomView extends FrameLayout {

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ZoomView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Zooming view listener interface.
     * 
     * @author karooolek
     * 
     */
    public interface ZoomViewListener {

        void onZoomStarted(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

        void onZooming(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

        void onZoomEnded(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);
    }

    // zooming
    float zoom = 1.0f;
    float maxZoom = 2.0f;
    float smoothZoom = 1.0f;
    float zoomX, zoomY;
    float smoothZoomX, smoothZoomY;
    private boolean scrolling; // NOPMD by karooolek on 29.06.11 11:45

    // minimap variables
    private boolean showMinimap = false;
    private int miniMapColor = Color.WHITE;
    private int miniMapHeight = -1;
    private String miniMapCaption;
    private float miniMapCaptionSize = 10.0f;
    private int miniMapCaptionColor = Color.WHITE;

    // touching variables
    private long lastTapTime;
    private float touchStartX, touchStartY;
    private float touchLastX, touchLastY;
    private float startd;
    private boolean pinching;
    private float lastd;
    private float lastdx1, lastdy1;
    private float lastdx2, lastdy2;

    // drawing
    private final Matrix m = new Matrix();
    private final Paint p = new Paint();

    // listener
    ZoomViewListener listener;

    private Bitmap ch;

    public float getZoom() {
        return zoom;
    }

    public float getMaxZoom() {
        return maxZoom;
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(final float maxZoom) {
        if (maxZoom < 1.0f) {
            return;
        }

        this.maxZoom = maxZoom;
    }

    public void setMiniMapEnabled(final boolean showMiniMap) {
        this.showMinimap = showMiniMap;
    }

    public boolean isMiniMapEnabled() {
        return showMinimap;
    }

    public void setMiniMapHeight(final int miniMapHeight) {
        if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.miniMapHeight = miniMapHeight;
    }

    public int getMiniMapHeight() {
        return miniMapHeight;
    }

    public void setMiniMapColor(final int color) {
        miniMapColor = color;
    }

    public int getMiniMapColor() {
        return miniMapColor;
    }

    public String getMiniMapCaption() {
        return miniMapCaption;
    }

    public void setMiniMapCaption(final String miniMapCaption) {
        this.miniMapCaption = miniMapCaption;
    }

    public float getMiniMapCaptionSize() {
        return miniMapCaptionSize;
    }

    public void setMiniMapCaptionSize(final float size) {
        miniMapCaptionSize = size;
    }

    public int getMiniMapCaptionColor() {
        return miniMapCaptionColor;
    }

    public void setMiniMapCaptionColor(final int color) {
        miniMapCaptionColor = color;
    }

    public void zoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
        this.zoom = Math.min(zoom, maxZoom);
        zoomX = x;
        zoomY = y;
        smoothZoomTo(this.zoom, x, y);
    }

    public void smoothZoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
        smoothZoom = clamp(1.0f, zoom, maxZoom);
        smoothZoomX = x;
        smoothZoomY = y;
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onZoomStarted(smoothZoom, x, y);
        }
    }

    public ZoomViewListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListner(final ZoomViewListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public float getZoomFocusX() {
        return zoomX * zoom;
    }

    public float getZoomFocusY() {
        return zoomY * zoom;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        // single touch
        if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1) {
            processSingleTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        // // double touch
        if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            processDoubleTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        // redraw
        getRootView().invalidate();
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    private void processSingleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {

        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
        final float h = miniMapHeight;
        final boolean touchingMiniMap = x >= 10.0f && x <= 10.0f + w
                && y >= 10.0f && y <= 10.0f + h;

        if (showMinimap && smoothZoom > 1.0f && touchingMiniMap) {
            processSingleTouchOnMinimap(ev);
        } else {
            processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(ev);
        }
    }

    private void processSingleTouchOnMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
        final float h = miniMapHeight;
        final float zx = (x - 10.0f) / w * getWidth();
        final float zy = (y - 10.0f) / h * getHeight();
        smoothZoomTo(smoothZoom, zx, zy);
    }

    private void processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        float lx = x - touchStartX;
        float ly = y - touchStartY;
        final float l = (float) Math.hypot(lx, ly);
        float dx = x - touchLastX;
        float dy = y - touchLastY;
        touchLastX = x;
        touchLastY = y;

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchStartX = x;
            touchStartY = y;
            touchLastX = x;
            touchLastY = y;
            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;
            lx = 0;
            ly = 0;
            scrolling = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (scrolling || (smoothZoom > 1.0f && l > 30.0f)) {
                if (!scrolling) {
                    scrolling = true;
                    ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                }
                smoothZoomX -= dx / zoom;
                smoothZoomY -= dy / zoom;
                return;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            // tap
            if (l < 30.0f) {
                // check double tap
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTime < 500) {
                    if (smoothZoom == 1.0f) {
                        smoothZoomTo(maxZoom, x, y);
                    } else {
                        smoothZoomTo(1.0f, getWidth() / 2.0f,
                                getHeight() / 2.0f);
                    }
                    lastTapTime = 0;
                    ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                    return;
                }

                lastTapTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                performClick();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        ev.setLocation(zoomX + (x - 0.5f * getWidth()) / zoom, zoomY
                + (y - 0.5f * getHeight()) / zoom);

        ev.getX();
        ev.getY();

        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private void processDoubleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        final float x1 = ev.getX(0);
        final float dx1 = x1 - lastdx1;
        lastdx1 = x1;
        final float y1 = ev.getY(0);
        final float dy1 = y1 - lastdy1;
        lastdy1 = y1;
        final float x2 = ev.getX(1);
        final float dx2 = x2 - lastdx2;
        lastdx2 = x2;
        final float y2 = ev.getY(1);
        final float dy2 = y2 - lastdy2;
        lastdy2 = y2;

        // pointers distance
        final float d = (float) Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        final float dd = d - lastd;
        lastd = d;
        final float ld = Math.abs(d - startd);

        Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startd = d;
            pinching = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (pinching || ld > 30.0f) {
                pinching = true;
                final float dxk = 0.5f * (dx1 + dx2);
                final float dyk = 0.5f * (dy1 + dy2);
                smoothZoomTo(Math.max(1.0f, zoom * d / (d - dd)), zoomX - dxk
                        / zoom, zoomY - dyk / zoom);
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        default:
            pinching = false;
            break;
        }

        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private float clamp(final float min, final float value, final float max) {
        return Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));
    }

    private float lerp(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
        return a + (b - a) * k;
    }

    private float bias(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
        return Math.abs(b - a) >= k ? a + k * Math.signum(b - a) : b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

        // do zoom
        zoom = lerp(bias(zoom, smoothZoom, 0.05f), smoothZoom, 0.2f);
        smoothZoomX = clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomX,
                getWidth() - 0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom);
        smoothZoomY = clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomY,
                getHeight() - 0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom);

        zoomX = lerp(bias(zoomX, smoothZoomX, 0.1f), smoothZoomX, 0.35f);
        zoomY = lerp(bias(zoomY, smoothZoomY, 0.1f), smoothZoomY, 0.35f);
        if (zoom != smoothZoom && listener != null) {
            listener.onZooming(zoom, zoomX, zoomY);
        }

        final boolean animating = Math.abs(zoom - smoothZoom) > 0.0000001f
                || Math.abs(zoomX - smoothZoomX) > 0.0000001f
                || Math.abs(zoomY - smoothZoomY) > 0.0000001f;

        // nothing to draw
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // prepare matrix
        m.setTranslate(0.5f * getWidth(), 0.5f * getHeight());
        m.preScale(zoom, zoom);
        m.preTranslate(
                -clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / zoom, zoomX, getWidth() - 0.5f
                        * getWidth() / zoom),
                -clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / zoom, zoomY, getHeight() - 0.5f
                        * getHeight() / zoom));

        // get view
        final View v = getChildAt(0);
        m.preTranslate(v.getLeft(), v.getTop());

        // get drawing cache if available
        if (animating && ch == null && isAnimationCacheEnabled()) {
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ch = v.getDrawingCache();
        }

        // draw using cache while animating
        if (animating && isAnimationCacheEnabled() && ch != null) {
            p.setColor(0xffffffff);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ch, m, p);
        } else { // zoomed or cache unavailable
            ch = null;
            canvas.save();
            canvas.concat(m);
            v.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        // draw minimap
        if (showMinimap) {
            if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
                miniMapHeight = getHeight() / 4;
            }

            canvas.translate(10.0f, 10.0f);

            p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
            final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
            final float h = miniMapHeight;
            canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, w, h, p);

            if (miniMapCaption != null && miniMapCaption.length() > 0) {
                p.setTextSize(miniMapCaptionSize);
                p.setColor(miniMapCaptionColor);
                p.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawText(miniMapCaption, 10.0f,
                        10.0f + miniMapCaptionSize, p);
                p.setAntiAlias(false);
            }

            p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
            final float dx = w * zoomX / getWidth();
            final float dy = h * zoomY / getHeight();
            canvas.drawRect(dx - 0.5f * w / zoom, dy - 0.5f * h / zoom, dx
                    + 0.5f * w / zoom, dy + 0.5f * h / zoom, p);

            canvas.translate(-10.0f, -10.0f);
        }

        // redraw
        // if (animating) {
        getRootView().invalidate();
        invalidate();
        // }
    }
}
```

then add your zoomable views in above custom view Note: custom view should have only one child that iss why added your zoomable views in RelativeLayout

```
   <com.pkg.pie.ZoomView
                android:id="@+id/zoomView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottomTitle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rlPieTitle"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/zoomView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

</TextView>


</RealtiveLayout>

            </com.pkg.pie.ZoomView>
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't want this i want like this for Tewxtview
http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

Comment: have you tried for above  I guess, it does exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**Refer [this link](https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView) to get exactly what you were looking for.**

Also add the following code snippet to your activity to execute in the TextView

```
StickerTextView tv_sticker = new StickerTextView(getContext());
tv_sticker.setText(“call me baby”);
canvas.addView(tv_sticker);
```

Comment: @ravi152 Check my answer you will get exactly what u need.